# Is there a way to split a text on multiple line by empty lines?

Tags: javascript, arrays, split, newline

If there is a text on multiple lines and you must split it based on new lines you do it like this:

```
const splitedText = inpitValue.split('\n');
```

This works fine for a text like the next one, it splits it into 3 parts.

```
this
is
my text
```

But is it a way to split it based on empty line?
For example for the following text it should be split into 2 parts only.

```
This
is 

a new 
text
```

Comment: Try  `^$` or `^[^\S\r\n]*$` for a single line, or `^\s*\r?\n` for multiple lines.

Comment: you should use `.split('\n\n');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
let inpitValue = `This
is

a new
text`;

const splitedText = inpitValue.split("\n\n");
console.log(splitedText);
```

Answer (score 1):

@aRvi is right

> you should use .split('\n\n');

```
const splitedText = inpitValue.split('\n\n');
```

Answer (score 1):

You could match 0+ whitespace chars from the start of the string followed by matching a newline to split on 1 or more "empty" lines if only spaces are also considered empty.

```
^\s*\r?\n
```

```js
let regex = /^\s*\r?\n/gm;
let inpitValue = `This
is

a new
text`;

const splitedText = inpitValue.split(regex);
console.log(splitedText);
```

To split on 2 or more newlines:

```
[\r\n]{2,}
```